# How to map two urls to one view?

Tags: django, django-urls

This is my class from models.py:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    persnr = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

This is my view:

```
def show_person(request, persnr):
    pers = get_object_or_404(Person, pk=persnr)
    context={'pers':pers}
    return render(request, 'company/person.html', context)
```

This is my url:

```
url(r'^show_person/(?P<persnr>\d+)', "company.views.show_person", name='show_person'),
```

How can I get to the same view (show_person) with these two urls:

```
server/show_person/(persnr)

server/show_person/(name)
```

Comment: What's stopping you creating another URL that captures the name? Except of course that that wouldn't work because the view is expecting a PK, so it's not clear why you would want both URLs to go to the same view.

Comment: I tried that, but did not know how to fix the error with the expected pk

Comment: I would recommend against having two identical pages with the same URL. You should pick one that you like, and then redirect the other one. For example take `show_person/123` to `show_person/john-smith`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A slightly different approach would be to accept two separate arguments, one for the pk and one for the name:

```
url(r'^show_person/(?P<persnr>\d+)', "company.views.show_person", name='show_person'),
url(r'^show_person/(?P<name>\w+)', "company.views.show_person", name='show_person'),

def show_person(request, persnr=None, name=None):
    if persnr is not None:
        pers = get_object_or_404(Person, pk=persnr)
    elif name is not None:
        pers = get_object_or_404(Person, name=name)
    else:
        raise Http404
```

Comment: Don't understand this way. Why IF statement? :)

Comment: Or: `(?P<pk>\d+)` and `def show_person(request, **kwargs): ... get_object_or_404(Person, **kwargs)` :-)

Comment: @Marin The url endpoints (in green) can either accept `persnr` or `name`. If they contain `persnr`, the if statement will execute. If they contain `name`, the elif statement will execute. If nothing is provided, it will raise Http404

Answer (score 3):

```
url(r'^show_person/(?P<persnr>.*)', "company.views.show_person", name='show_person'),

def show_person(request, persnr):
    per = Person.objects.filter(Q(name=persnr)|Q(persnr=persnr)).all()
    context={'pers':pers}
    return render(request, 'company/person.html', context)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
pers = get_object_or_404(Person, Q(name=persnr)|Q(persnr=persnr))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use django-arg-path library if you don't want to use dynamic urls
https://pypi.org/project/django-arg-path/0.2/

Answer (score -2):

I think it would be more clear to write 2 URLs mapping to the same view function:

```
url(r'^show_person/(?P<persnr_or_name>\d+)', "company.views.show_person", name='show_person'),
url(r'^show_person/(?P<persnr_or_name>.*)', "company.views.show_person", name='show_person'),


def show_person(request, persnr_or_name):
    if persnr_or_name.isdigit():
        pers = get_object_or_404(Person, pk=persnr_or_name)
    else:
        pers = get_object_or_404(Person, name=persnr_or_name)
    context={'pers':pers}
    return render(request, 'company/person.html', context)
```

And there's a assumption that you don't allow pure number as name as most site do.

But to me, I preferer:

```
url(r'^show_person/(?P<persnr_or_name>\d+)', "company.views.show_person", name='show_person_by_pk'),
url(r'^show_person/(?P<persnr_or_name>.*)', "company.views.show_person", name='show_person_by_name'),


def show_person_by_pk(request, pk):
    pers = Person.objects.get_or_404(pk)
    context={'pers':pers}
    return render(request, 'company/person.html', context)

def show_person_by_name(request, name):
    pers = get_object_or_404(Person, name=name)
    context={'pers':pers}
    return render(request, 'company/person.html', context)
```

And the code of view can be shortened to 2 lines if you wish.

Comment: No need of two urls here. Anyway you are checking with `isinstance`. `.*` is enough for your `view`.

Comment: @itzmeontv It would be more clear if you define them in URL module than it in view module. And this is what I always preferred in programming -- declaration is better than progressive.

Comment: Good. But `persnr_or_name` will expect both since you declared that. So no more negatives in the sense of declaration.Otherwise you should do `persnr` and `name` seperately.Also `(?P<persnr_or_name>\d+` is not accepting name anyway.

Comment: This won't work; the argument will always be a string, even if the value it captures is numeric. You'd need to try and convert it to an int and catch the error.

Comment: @DanielRoseman You are right, I've fixed this issue. And your answer is the same as what I thought after a few thinking.